# How to set mysql_query('set Names utf8') in wp-db file in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, utf-8

I am developing a kurdish site in wordpress. I want to fetch all datas by Kurdish alphabetical order.

For example

```
$alpha='ش';
 $results =$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."books where `author_name` like '$alpha%'");
print_r($results);
```

this returns nothing.

But when  I run this query with english alphabet it works fine. I know `mysql_query('set Names utf8')` is the solution for this type of problem in core php but i dont know where and how to set this `mysql_query('set Names utf8')`; in wp-db.php of wordpress

Answer (score 1):

When your tables are UTF-8 but your connections is not, try to set the following constant:

```
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
```

You can also set the column encoding:

```
define( 'DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci' );
```

**WARNING**: Make sure you have a backup of your database before chaning anything on the encodings.

If all of this is not the issue, the script you set the `$alpha` variable in might not be encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: hi i already set these lines in my wp-config.php file define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );define( 'DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci' ); and also i run this code $results =$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."books where `author_name` like 'و%'"); again it shows Warning error : mysql_set_charset(): Error executing query in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 776

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of your PHP script files?

Comment: i dont know how to check this please tell me

Comment: Ah, so you are on a windows machine. Changes are quite high, you are using the windows-1252 encoding. Open the file a an editor/IDE, that show you the encoding. If you have notepad++ installed, open the file and choose "Encoding" from the menu. The option "Encoded in UTF-8 without BOM" should be checked. If you, select all the code (STRG+A) and choose "Encoding > Covert to UTF-8 without BOM" from the menu.

Comment: BTW: You shold also escape the variable correctly: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8847